# Are location request made before the Google Api Client is connected enqueued?

Tags: android, api, location, google-play, google-play-services

I'd like to know if I make a location request before the Google Api Client is connected, will the request be enqueued and performed after the client is connected?

From [Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) of Google's Android training, it seems no:

> Before requesting location updates, your app must connect to location services and make a location request. The lesson on Changing Location Settings shows you how to do this. Once a location request is in place you can start the regular updates by calling requestLocationUpdates(). Do this in the onConnected() callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready.

But from this [Google Android blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2014/02/new-client-api-model-in-google-play.html), it does not seem impossible:

> Another new feature is enqueuing of API calls, which allows you to call read methods before the API clients are connected.

So will I receive location updates if I call the following before the Google Api Client is connected?

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    mGoogleApiClient,
    mLocationRequest,
    this);
```

where `this` is a `LocationListener`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) in my researches and it might also help you.

Volley offers the following benefits:

> - Automatic scheduling of network requests.
> - Multiple concurrent network connections.
> - Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache
>     coherence.
> - Support for request prioritization.
> - Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can
>     set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
> - Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
> - Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with
>     data fetched asynchronously from the network.
> - Debugging and tracing tools.

With this, you have an option to manage how to handle queuing of location requests. You can set up a request queue to supply your own custom behavior with the use of convenience method called `Volley.newRequestQueue`.

If you just need to make a one-time request and don't want to leave the thread pool around, you can create the RequestQueue wherever you need it and call stop() on the RequestQueue once your response or error has come back, using the Volley.newRequestQueue() method.

[Setting up a RequestQueue](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) needs the following two things to do its job:

> 1. a network to perform transport of the requests
> 2. a cache to handle caching

A snippet is given in the documentation which shows the steps involved in setting up a `RequestQueue`.

In addition to that snippet, this SO post - [How do I use the Volley network request queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106483/how-do-i-use-the-volley-network-request-queue) might also give you solution on how it is implemented.