# Best way to call Volley network call multiple times

Tags: android, android-volley

I have one requirement, where I have to call Volley POST method near about 300-500 times. In post I am sending JSONObject and in response I am getting String as output. But my problem is when I call volley on some devices I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` because calling service more than 300 times. Following is my code:

```
for (int i=0;i<myJsonArr.length();i++) // here myJsonArr  may contains 300-500 json object
        {
            customRequestTest(allAppJson.getJSONObject(i));
        }


public void customRequestTest(JSONObject jsonObject)
{
    try {
        String myURL = "My URL";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String mRequestBody = jsonObject.toString();
        System.out.println (">>>>>>>>>>mRequestBody"+mRequestBody);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, myURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("LOG_RESPONSE", response);
                System.out.println (">>>>>>>>onResponse"+response +" for request "+mRequestBody);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("LOG_RESPONSE", error.toString());
                System.out.println (">>>>>>>>onErrorResponse"+error.toString()+" for request "+mRequestBody);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    String str = new String(response.data);
                    responseString = str;
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println (">>>>>>>>Inside catch of customRequestTest");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

getting Out of memory erorr at : `RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`

Comment: Check older request is complete before making new

Comment: I think volley request queue will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106483/how-do-i-use-the-volley-network-request-queue

Comment: This is occurring because you are creating the `RequestQueue` instance multiple times by passing the `activity context`. You should create the `instance` once using an `Application context` and then use it again and again whenever needed. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333574/8009433)

Comment: @NavneetKrishna. Thanks for suggestion now its not crashing, Still I will check same on other devices also. Thanks

Comment: @NavneetKrishna Done. Thanks